# Before Insert Trigger not firing

Tags: mysql, trigger, centos

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER `merchant_insert` BEFORE INSERT ON `merchant_table` FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO merchant_seq VALUES (NULL);
  SET NEW.merchant_id = CONCAT('MC', LPAD(LAST_INSERT_ID(), 10, '0'));
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Please consider elaborating on what's happening and how you can see the trigger is not firing, so that the issue is clear.

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO merchant_seq VALUES (NULL);
SET @last_ID = (SELECT MAX(merchant_id) FROM merchant_seq);
SET NEW.merchant_id = CONCAT('MC', LPAD(@last_ID, 10, '0'));
```

Comment: I want to add new.merchant_id for "merchant_table", merchant_id is not for merchant_seq.  "merchant_seq" table is used for auto increment.

CREATE TABLE `merchant_seq` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB

CREATE TABLE `tbl_m_merchant` (
  `merchant_id` varchar(12) NOT NULL,
  `created_date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `updated_date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`merchant_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

Comment: I updated my answer.